# Pass value from android app to php without using NameValuepair

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to make my first android application which is like a rss feed.The sample app is shown in below link
[json-feed-reader-in-android](http://javatechig.com/android/json-feed-reader-in-android)

I am able to connect to the database and populate the custom listview on my first activity.However for my second screen,i want to retrieve information from the database depending upon the user choice from the list from 1st screen. Fot this i need to pass this choice to php script.

I have looked for this information ,but most of the solutions are with namepair  which is deprecated . I am not able to understand how to do it with htpurlconnection.

what can i use to pass a value to php script .if there is some resource which can be useful,please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use GET query parameters:

```
  URL url = new URL("http://your.feed.host/?choice={choiceVariableGoesHere}");
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  try {
      InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
      readStream( in );
      finally {
          urlConnection.disconnect();
      }
  }
```

And then in your php read the `choice` from `$_GET`:

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
```

If you want to do it with POST you could do as follows:

```
String choiceVariable = 'first'; //Example
URL url = new URL("http://your.feed.host/");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("choice", choiceVariable);
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
output.close();

connection.connect();
```

And then in your php read the `choice` from `$_POST`:

```
$choice = $_POST['choice'];
```

Comment: Indeed. But `$_GET` is not recommended for transferring sensitive information. `$_POST` is the best choice for that

Comment: @taxicala thx for repling bro...i will try this out.  is there any resource explaining the concept behind this code,as i want to understand whats happening there. o know its basic thing,but i am not able to understand it

Comment: I believe the documentation for HttpURLConnection would be the first place you should check.

Comment: @taxicala one basic doubt bro,, how can i check whether the value i am sending is being recieved by php script

Comment: try var_dump($_POST);